# In Proverbs 1:8 is it "mother's law" or "mother's instruction"?

Tags: hebrew, word-study, law, torah, teaching

Could the word ‘torah’ be more universal in use as law/teaching/instruction or could this use in proverbs mean that the mother also taught the Law?

I guess what I am trying to ascertain is whether this would have been considered the Halacha in a sense that it was general teaching or could this also be referring to the Law, Torah rather than torah.

Proverbs 1:8
“Listen, my son, to your father’s instruction and do not forsake your mother’s teaching.” (Torah)

‘The Law of your mother’ OR “The teachings/instruction of your mother’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MT for Proverbs 1:8 is:

> שְׁמַע, בְּנִי, מוּסַר אָבִיךָ, וְאַל תִּטֹּשׁ תּוֹרַת אִמֶּךָ

This verse is a [paralleism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_poetry#Parallelism) in which the words "instruction" (מוסר) and "teaching" (תורה) are parallel. That is "instruction" and "teaching" are used as loose synonyms. This points to a non-proper use of "torah" rather than **the** "Torah" of Moses. Furthermore, from the context of the first seven verses of the chapter it is clear that the author is writing about wisdom in a general sense rather than a specific sense.

Another telling parallelism in this verse is "father" and "mother". That is, these words are used as synonyms, which hints that they were intended as collective singulars for "fathers" and "mothers" of previous generations and not necessarily your specific father and mother. In other words, you should respect and accept the collective tribal teaching that your parents generation has passed on to you, in addition to seeking wisdom on your own as exhorted in the preceding verses.

The position of women in the ancient world was generally not as teachers of the Torah. Before washing machines, manufactured food, cheap clothing from China, and daycare, women were usually completely and totally occupied with the daily chores of the household. Furthermore, the model of Torah transmission in the MT is the Levite and priestly classes.